# Django. How to remove duplicate requests in a Modelform

Tags: django, optimization, django-forms, duplicates

model. py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField()
    attribute1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    attribute2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    attribute3 = models.ForeignKey(ModelTwo)
```

forms.py

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        ModelOne_choice = [(fields.id, fields.__str__()) for fields in ModelOne.objects.all()]
        self.fields['attribute1'].choices = ModelOne_choice 
        self.fields['attribute2'].choices = ModelOne_choice
```

My current model has many foreign keys including different attributes pointing to the same foreign key. django debug_toolbar shows about 10 requests when creating a form. How can this number be minimized?
I have used ModelOne_choice for repeated foreign keys. Tried Raw requests.

As I understand it, when a project is launched into production, such a number of calls to the database is very bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to add select_related when you're calling your model:

```
ModelOne_choice = [(fields.id, fields.__str__()) for fields in ModelOne.objects.all().select_related('attribute1 ', 'attribute2', 'attribute3')]
```

Comment: thanks, but attribute3 is not taken from ModelOne